# Gradle: Password Verification failed - Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, passwords, alias, verification

I have a problem with gradle saying **"Password verification failed"** when I rebuild my project right after I clean the project. The funny thing is that when I **"Generate Signed Bundle/Apk"** using my key store password and key password, my project doesn't complain about any passwords and completes the compiling for a pro-release or free-release version of the app and the app works fine on an device from side loading the apk. So I know the passwords and alias names are correct but setting up **"proRelease"** or **"freeRelease"** as build variant when testing app with an plugged in device get the **"Password verification failed"** message. I've tried to change my gradle version, remove .gradle folder and invalidate caches/restart, but none worked. Any fixes for something like this? Thx

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to read key "namealias" from store "nameKeyStore.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```